# What to tell postgresql client not to clear output when quit

Tags: postgresql

When you display a very long table's structure using \d tablename, postgres client (psql 9.1.7) try to manage the output, and display "(END)" on the end. But when you quit, it clear very thing.

How can I tell postgres not to clear it? Like lower version (psql 8.1.23) did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that PostgreSQL is sending output to a pager (like `less` or `more`) if it won't fit entirely on one screen.

If you don't want it to do this, unset set the `PAGER` environment variable or use `\pset pager off`.